# Google Maps API rotate Rectangle along its vertices

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an application which has a rectangle on a google map at the certain point, I have to rotate the rectangle along the vertices as well as it should be editable, but the width of the rectangle should be always greater than its height.

I have seen several other solutions on stack overflow for rectangle rotation, there it is suggested to user polyline or polygon, but as I need angle difference of 90 between each side so I can't shift to other shapes.

Here is my code:

```
   var rectangle;
   var map;
   var markers = [];
   var north_east_degree=30;
   var south_west_degree=210;

   var center = new google.maps.LatLng(18.5021, 73.8774);   // Circle center

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: center,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
  zoom: 90,
  heading: 90,
  tilt: 45
});

  var north_point=center.destinationPoint(north_degree, 0.08); 
  var east_point=center.destinationPoint(east_degree, 0.08);
  var south_point=center.destinationPoint(south_degree, 0.08); 
  var west_point=center.destinationPoint(west_degree, 0.08);

   var bounds = {
    north: north_point.lat(),
    east: east_point.lng(),
    south: south_point.lat(),
    west: west_point.lng()
   };

   rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    bounds: bounds,
    editable: true,
    draggable: true,
    strokeColor: "#000000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    zIndex: -1
   });

  rectangle.setMap(map);
```

as there is no rotate event available for rectangle so for now I have used on click event:[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCG5s.png)

```
 rectangle.addListener('click', rotate_rect);
```

initially, i get this result if i maintain angles as given above, at second iteration, every angle increases by 30 it then rectangle looks quite slanted the at third click rectangle changes to be as a single line as angle difference between each side is the very small I guess.

```
  function rotate_rect(event)
   {
     var nor_east = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
     var south_west = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();
     x1 = nor_east.lat();
     x2 = south_west.lat();
     y1 = nor_east.lng();
     y2 = south_west.lng();

     var cx= x1 + ((x2 - x1) / 2);
     var cy = y1 + ((y2 - y1) / 2);
      cx = cx.toPrecision(6);
     cy= cy.toPrecision(6)

   var center_rec = new google.maps.LatLng(cx,cy);

   north_east_degree=north_east_degree+30;
   south_west_degree=south_west_degree+30;
   if(north_east_degree==180){
     north_east_degree=30;
     south_west_degree=210;

   }



  var newPointNorthEast=center_rec.destinationPoint(north_east_degree, calcCrow(center_rec.lat(),center_rec.lng(),nor_east.lat(),nor_east.lng()).toFixed(2));
  var newPointSouthWest=center_rec.destinationPoint(south_west_degree, calcCrow(center_rec.lat(),center_rec.lng(),south_west.lat(),south_west.lng()).toFixed(2));

  var bounds = {
    north: newPointNorthEast.lat(),
    south: newPointSouthWest.lat(),
    east: newPointNorthEast.lng(),
    west: newPointSouthWest.lng()
   };

   rectangle.setBounds(bounds);

}//rotate_rect
```

Comment: What is `.destinationPoint`?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  Note that on a sphere (or an oblate spheriod) a rectangles corner angles will not be 90 degrees.

Comment: And a bounds object is always oriented along lines of latitude/longitude

Answer (score 2):

You cant properly rotate rectangle in Google Maps since [`google.maps.Rectangle` object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Rectangle) *does not support to set/get coordinates of the four vertices* (with `setBounds` function it is supported to set `northeast` and `southwest` coordinates only)

Instead you could consider the following solution:

- create a polygon from a rectangle object and display it on the map
- rotate a polygon

**Working example**

```js
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: { lat: 33.678, lng: -116.243 },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map,
        bounds: {
            north: 33.685,
            south: 33.671,
            east: -116.224,
            west: -116.251
        }
    });

    var rectPoly = createPolygonFromRectangle(rectangle); //create a polygom from a rectangle

    rectPoly.addListener('click', function(e) {
        rotatePolygon(rectPoly,10);
    });


    document.getElementById('btnRotate').onclick = function() {
        window.setInterval(function() {
            rotatePolygon(rectPoly, 10);
        }, 500);
    };
}



function createPolygonFromRectangle(rectangle) {
    var map = rectangle.getMap();
  
    var coords = [
      { lat: rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), lng: rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng() },
      { lat: rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), lng: rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng() },
      { lat: rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(), lng: rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng() },
      { lat: rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(), lng: rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng() }
    ];

    // Construct the polygon.
    var rectPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: coords
    });
    var properties = ["strokeColor","strokeOpacity","strokeWeight","fillOpacity","fillColor"];
    //inherit rectangle properties 
    var options = {};
    properties.forEach(function(property) {
        if (rectangle.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            options[property] = rectangle[property];
        }
    });
    rectPoly.setOptions(options);

    rectangle.setMap(null);
    rectPoly.setMap(map);
    return rectPoly;
}


function rotatePolygon(polygon,angle) {
    var map = polygon.getMap();
    var prj = map.getProjection();
    var origin = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(polygon.getPath().getAt(0)); //rotate around first point

    var coords = polygon.getPath().getArray().map(function(latLng){
       var point = prj.fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
       var rotatedLatLng =  prj.fromPointToLatLng(rotatePoint(point,origin,angle));
       return {lat: rotatedLatLng.lat(), lng: rotatedLatLng.lng()};
    });
    polygon.setPath(coords);
}

function rotatePoint(point, origin, angle) {
    var angleRad = angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
    return {
        x: Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) - Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.x,
        y: Math.sin(angleRad) * (point.x - origin.x) + Math.cos(angleRad) * (point.y - origin.y) + origin.y
    };
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="floating-panel"><input type="button" id="btnRotate" value="Auto Rotate"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vgrem/70sL1kg6/)

Comment: Update
Thanks for the help.

My goal is to give a rectangle for selection of the ground on google map, so user should be able to adjust rectangle according to the size of the ground and he should be able to increase size of the rectangle if it won't fit with the ground, he should be able to rotate/adjust the vertices according to his own choice among(A,B,C,D) so that the rectangle is adjusted with the ground.